# Extending $G$-equivariant local diffeomorphisms on principal bundles to local bundle maps

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, connections

Consider a principal $G$-bundle $P$ over the base space $M$ equipped with a connection 1-form $\omega$. Let $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ be open subsets of $P$, and suppose $F: \mathcal{U} \to \mathcal{V}$ is a $G$-equivariant local diffeomorphism leaving $\omega$ invariant, i.e. $F^*\omega = \omega$. The question arises: can we extend $F$ to a local bundle map $\tilde{F}: \pi^{-1}(U) \to \pi^{-1}(V)$ for some open subsets $U, V \subset M$, ensuring that $\tilde{F}^*\omega = \omega$ holds?